# Существует ли средство для проверки актуальности версии программы?

Tags: json, контроль-версий, версионность

Нужно узнать, является ли актуальной (последней) версия программы.

Существует ли какое-то стандартное решение задачи проверки версий ПО?

Comment: Нет, база версий не имеет какого-либо стандарта, её номер остаётся на усмотрение разработчика. Следовательно, вы не найдете то, что хотите. Это возможно только в библиотеках, на каком-нибудь MavenCentral хранится вся история версий. А насчет программ - нет. Только если на официальном сайте этой программы. Или на TrashBox. Там можно скачать программу по версиии

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.

Comment: @Nicolas Chabanovsky, А что собственно не ясно???

Comment: Вообще ничего, если честно.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, не понимаю людей которые лепят минус если не могут понять элементарного вопроса... Я спросил Существует ли какой-нибудь API, к которому я могу обратится, указав в качестве параметра название программы, а в ответ получил ее версию к примеру: Request https://program-api.com/request?pname=Skype | Response: Name:Skype, Version: 6.22.1.2

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы узнать, является ли версия программы актуальной (последней), нужно сравнить описание версии имеющейся программы с описанием актуальной (последней) версии. Обычно, версии пишутся в цифробуквенном формате, слева направо. Например 1.0а или 56.456.i.34. Сравнение будет идти по группам слева направо. Соответственно, если сравниваемая версия отличается в меньшую сторону, значит, что она не актуальная.